# Proving all conformal mappings from the upper half-plane to the unit disc take a certain form

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Bit confused about the above solution... why is the inverse of $\phi$, $w = \frac{i-z}{i+z}$, substituted into $$e^{i\mu}\frac{\alpha - w}{1 - \overline{\alpha}w}?$$

What exactly is the solution trying to accomplish? It stated that $g \circ \phi: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$, and I know by (Theorem 2.2) that there exist $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}$ such that

$$(g \circ \phi)(z) = e^{i\mu}\frac{\alpha - z}{1 - \overline{\alpha}z}$$

So why does the solution state that $$g(z) = e^{i\mu}\frac{\alpha - z}{1 - \overline{\alpha}z}?$$

Is this a typo?

Is the author substituting the inverse of $\phi$ to "undo" $\phi$ and recover $g(z)$? Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: can you also give a reference to Theorem 2.2 or otherwise include it to this question?

Comment: would you mind sharing from which book this screenshot was?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that the author uses the variable $z$ when referring to elements of the **upper half plane**, and $w$ when referring to elements of the unit **disk**. This is where you confusion comes from.

The spirit of the proof is to use that you already know how the automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$ are. So, when the author writes $g(z)$ he's actually doing this: 
$$
g(z) = g((\phi\circ\psi)(z)) = (g\circ\phi)(w)
$$ 
Then, since $g\circ\phi$ is an automoprhism of the disk, he can use that canonical form you already know and substitute $w$ as a function of $z$. You can do this because $\phi$ and $\psi$ give you a bijective way of doing it.