# Complex Analysis - looking for a certain book (screenshot included)

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I hope this kind of question is tolerated and not against any rule. After searching for a problem i stumpled upon this question

[Proving all conformal mappings from the upper half-plane to the unit disc take a certain form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1037121/543570)

and i am looking for the book from which the given screenshot has been taken of:

[image]

Does someone happen to recognize what book that could be? I would appreciate any hint.

Thank you very much.

Comment: google search for the exact string "has unit length because conjugation preserves norm" suggests it could be some Solutions to the book Stein & Shakarchi - Complex Analysis

Comment: i did that and it lead me to Stein & Shakarchi but i couldn't find the solutions to it. thanks nonetheless.